# Using css position:sticky; leaves part of image hidden

Tags: css, css-position

Pretty much the title, I have a webpage with a few images, using an effect achieved with position:sticky; using this toutorial https://library.superhi.com/posts/parallax-overlapping-sections-using-sticky-positioning The problem lies with the images being larger in height than the computer screen so when it reaches the top, I can't see the bottom of the immage. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: can't you resize the image to the proportion matching the screen size ? adjust the height and width to fit in the single view without breaking.